# Splitting 800mb file in smaller text files

Tags: split, git-bash

I am trying to split huge text file into smaller txt files. I am using gitbash. With split command

```
split myfilename -l 39000
```

I am able to split many files with 39000 lines. But I want to split each file after 39000 line the first line start with H.

Comment: For what purpose? Not because large files are hard for git to track? Otherwise you can use git-lfs...

Comment: Some flat files 832, 837 kind of files for processing jobs